# Factor of $(2\pi)^4$ in momentum space Feynman rule

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum, conventions, fourier-transform, dirac-delta-distributions

I'm trying to figure out the momentum space Feynman rules using Peskin and Schroeder. For simplicity I'll ask about section 4.6 for case of the $\phi^4$ theory.

In section 4.5, we have $$\tag{4.72}S=1+iT$$ gives the definition of the $T$  and $$\tag{4.73}\langle p_1p_2...|iT|k_A k_B\rangle=(2\pi)^4\delta^4(k_A+k_B-\sum p_f)\cdot i\mathcal{M}(k_A,k_B\rightarrow p_f).$$

In section 4.6, on page 114 we have the position space Feynman rule:

$$\tag{4.103} i\mathcal{M}\cdot (2\pi)^4 \delta^4(p_A+p_B-\sum p_f)= \text{sum of all connected amputated diagrams}$$

but the momentum space Feynman rule becomes

$$\tag{4.104} i\mathcal{M}=\text{sum of all connected,amputated digrams}.$$

I get the cancellation of the delta function $\delta^4(k_A+k_B-\sum p_f)$, but what happened to the factor $(2\pi)^4$ in the position space? Is this a typo?

Later on page 115, Peskin and Schroeder says "impose momentum conservation at each vertex", I believe this means, for each vertex, we include a factor $(2\pi)^4\delta^4(\sum p_{\text{incoming}}-p_{\text{outgoing}})$, where incoming and outgoing mean relative to the given vertex. Therefore I think Peskin and Schroeder 4.104 should have included a factor of $(2\pi)^4$ on the left.

Comment: No, the $(2\pi)^4$ is supposed to be there. Every momentum integration comes with a $1/(2\pi)^4$ because of the Fourier transform convention. So the $(2\pi)^4$ on the delta functions cancels that.

Comment: Do you mean in the left hand side of momentum space Feynman rule there isn't or is a $(2\pi)^4$?

Comment: My understanding is that in the position space, every propogator has a $(2\pi)^4$ at the bottom and every vertex integral causes a $(2\pi)^4$ as a result of $\int d^4x e^{ipx}=(2\pi)^4 \delta(p)$

Comment: The factor of $(2\pi)^4$ stays as the normalization of Fourier transforms. When you go back to position space you'll take $\int\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}e^{-ik\cdot x}$ where the factor cancels out.

Comment: By the way, all these $(2\pi)^\#$ could be avoided if you define your Fourier transforms with $\mathrm{e}^{\pm 2\pi\mathrm{i}\, p\cdot x}$.